# can't call functions from arduino library

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

When i try to call any function from my library, it gives the following error:

```
In function 'void setup()':
error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token
netti.SetupWifi();
^
```

Yesterday it worked fine and i'm pretty sure that i haven't changed anything so i have no idea what's wrong with it. The library is for making wifi connection and telnet monitoring easier.

Adruino code:

```
#include <netti.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  netti.SetupWifi(); //error here
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  netti.ReconnectWifi(); //same error here
  Serial.println("runs"); // test so it's running atleast some code
  delay(1000);
  

}
```

netti.h:

```
#ifndef netti_h
#define netti_h

#if (ARDUINO >= 100)
    #include "Arduino.h"
#else
    #include "WProgram.h"
#endif

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

class netti{
    public:
    //constructor
    netti(bool displayMsg=false);
    //methods
    void SetupWifi();
    void ReconnectWifi();
    void SetupMobile(); // for different wifi
    void ReconnectMobile(); //for different wifi
    WiFiClient Telnet;
    private:
    

};

#endif
```

and netti.cpp:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include "netti.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <PubSubClient.h>

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 100);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 0, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);

WiFiServer TelnetServer(23);
WiFiClient Telnet;


netti::netti(bool displayMsg){
  Serial.println("netti kirjasto käytössä");
}

void(* resetFunc) (void) = 0;

void handleTelnet(){
  Telnet.println("test");
  Serial.println("telnet handler called");
  if (TelnetServer.hasClient()){
    if (!Telnet || !Telnet.connected()){
      if(Telnet) Telnet.stop();
      Serial.println("telnet available");
      Telnet =TelnetServer.available();
      
    }else {
      TelnetServer.available().stop();
      Serial.println("telnet in use");
    }
  }
}

void netti::SetupWifi() {
  delay(100);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println("wifi");
  WiFi.hostname("ESP_host");
  WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);
  WiFi.begin("wifi name","pass place");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  };

  randomSeed(micros());
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  TelnetServer.begin();
  TelnetServer.setNoDelay(true);
};


void netti::ReconnectWifi() {
  int i=0;
  handleTelnet();
  Telnet.println("test2"); // does nothing, why??
  if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(5000);
      SetupWifi();
    };
};

void netti::SetupMobile() {
  delay(100);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println("mobile");
  WiFi.hostname("ESP_host");
  WiFi.begin("mobile_place","pass place");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  };

  randomSeed(micros());

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  TelnetServer.begin();
  TelnetServer.setNoDelay(true);
};


void netti::ReconnectMobile() {
  int i=0;
  handleTelnet();
  if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(5000);
    SetupMobile();
  }
};
```

This is my first attempt at making my own library and i have no idea why it's not working.
Thanks in advance for all the help

PS. I'm having trouble with Telnet, trying to work the solution, which is hard, when the library doesn't run

Comment: please show the full compiler output

Comment: The actual error should read "error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token FOO" where FOO will be replaced by some thing in your source. As @AlanBirtles says you need to include more of the error output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is the following. You have defined a class called *netti* but you have not created an instance of the class. Therefore you cannot call instance methods on this class. For example if you have

```
class netti{
    public:
    //constructor
    netti(bool displayMsg=false);
    //methods
    void SetupWifi();
    void ReconnectWifi();
    void SetupMobile(); // for different wifi
    void ReconnectMobile(); //for different wifi
    WiFiClient Telnet;
    private:
    

};
```

you need to write

```
netti  netti_instance(true);
netti_instance.SetupWifi();
```

If you want to be able to call methods on a class without an instance you need to declare them as [*static* methods](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_static_members.htm#:%7E:text=By%20declaring%20a%20function%20member,the%20scope%20resolution%20operator%20%3A%3A.).

I suggest you look into some basic tutorials on how to use C++ classes.

Comment: Do you know why in ReconnectWifi() the Telnet.print.ln

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, In ReconnectWifi() Telnet.println should print test2 to telnet server. It doesen't work. Though in handleTelnet()  telnet.println works perfctly. I'm wondering if it has something to do with global variable telnet